# Why is `session` method with `didRemove [ARAnchor]` never called for `ARBodyTrackingConfiguration`?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am using the [`ARSessionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate) on an [`ARView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview) where I initialize the [`ARBodyTrackingConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arbodytrackingconfiguration).

The [`session`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate#2880566) methods with [`didAdd: [ARAnchor]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865617-session) and [`didUpdate: [ARAnchor]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865624-session) are called correctly. But [`didRemove: [ARAnchor]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865622-session) is never called.

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865622-session), anchors "may" be automatically removed from the session, depending on the session configuration. I did not find a setting for this though.

Does anybody know why the `session` method with `didRemove [ARAnchor]` is never called and which setting I need to change to get it to work?

```swift
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import UIKit

class AugmentedVideoView: ARView, ARSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        print("didAdd") // called correctly
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        print("didUpdate") // called correctly
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didRemove anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        print("didRemove") // is never called :-(
    }

    required init(frame: CGRect) {
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        handleError("Camera not available in simulator.")
        return

        #else
        super.init(frame: frame,
                   cameraMode: ARView.CameraMode.ar,
                   automaticallyConfigureSession: false)
        self.session.delegate = self

        guard ARBodyTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {
            handleError("Your device does not support body tracking.")
            return
        }

        let configuration = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.automaticSkeletonScaleEstimationEnabled = false
        self.session.run(configuration)
        #endif
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    dynamic required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I understood it by now. Even if the person is not detected anymore, `ARKit` just assumes it is still where it was detected last. This applies e. g. if the person is out of sight.
If the person is out of sight and another person is detected, `ARKit` is not clever enough to detect it as another person. It just updates the old anchor, assuming it is the same one.